# guzzle 6.3 post async request

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to send post async request

```
    $client = new Client([

        'timeout'  => 2.0,

    ]);

    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'localhost/test.php' , [   'json' => [
        "username"=>"xyz",
        "password"=>"xyz",
        "first_name"=>"test",
        "last_name"=>"test",
        "email"=>"test@test.com",
        "roles"=>"Administrator"
    ], ]);

    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {

        echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
    });
    $promise->wait();
```

test.php code is 
`var_dump($_POST);`

The result should be the variables that i've set, but i get empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using `"json" => []`, you might have to use `"form_params" => []` to get things populated to the `$_POST` array.

See some documentation here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params

The `json` option is used for RESTful APIs that explicitly require json as input, but in php normally `$_POST` is populated with the posted form, for example the named `<input>`s in a `<form>`

Comment: I do it for the community, no doubt people still stumble upon this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a scheduler function like below , read the [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

this function will be called at end of php script, so its a good time to close the connection and continue the heavy jobs.

```php
    public static function schedulePromise($callable, ...$args)
    {
        register_shutdown_function(function ($callable, ...$args) {
            @session_write_close();
            @ignore_user_abort(true);
            call_user_func($callable, ...$args);
        }, $callable, ...$args);
    }
```

And the user never feels the heavy work behind the scenes. for example waiting for request in guzzle http

```php
        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request, ['timeout' => 10])
            ->then(function ($response) {
                // success
            }, function ($response) {
                // failure
            });
        self::schedulePromise([$promise, 'wait'],false);
```